# Leaflet - How to query rendered features in Vector tiles

Tags: leaflet, mapbox-gl-js

I am new to leaflet. currently I am working on leaflet to render vector tiles. my application's requirement is that on click i should get features from map tiles in geojson format.
In Mapbox `map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point)`. I want to do exact same thing, but in leaflet. Please check [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/) to check how mapbox is fetching features.
 Please help.

Comment: Have you tried interactivity with Leaflet.VectorGrid ?

Comment: I have checked this plugin but it does not fullfil my requirement. Basically, I need geometry of road elements in form of geojson.

Comment: What library are you using to render the vector tiles?

Comment: Stupid question but what are the reasons you dont switch to MapboxGL it's actively maintained and specfically written for vector tilesets you can load third party tilesets in so your not locked into the Mapbox stack...

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ I am using leaflet 1.0 for rendering vector tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Leaflet implementation does not supports querying rendered features. Hence switching to Mapboxgl